# UIImagePicker not showing Original Image from Photos Library in OS 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller

Holy Crap! Really... I'm frustrated with this problem that get me stuck with my apps for a week now.

Here is the code

```
- (IBAction)loadTheImage {


 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

 picker.delegate = self;

 picker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

 // picker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

If I set the source as SavedPhotosAlbum (Camera Roll), then it works OK. But when I set it to PhotoLibrary, it just returns nil. And this just happens in OS3.1.2. In OS4 it works OK (ie returns the original image just fine).

Anybody?

Comment: What exactly is nil? Is it just the value for the original image or is it the entire user info dictionary? Is the picker value nil?

Answer (score 0):

A given source may not always be available on every device. This could be because the source is not physically present or because it cannot currently be accessed.

Before attempting to use an UIImagePickerController object to pick an image, you must call `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:]` method to ensure that the desired source type is available.